# too many arguments for constructor MyWebSocketActor in Play 2.5.x and Akka 2.4.7

Tags: java, scala, playframework, akka, actor

```
class MyWebSocketActorTest extends Specification with Mockito {

  val system = ActorSystem("MockActorSystem")
  val mockMap : Map[ActorRef , String] = Map()
  val mockCache = mock[CacheApi]
  val actor1 = system.actorOf(Props[ChatActor],"actor1")
  val actor2 = system.actorOf(Props[ChatActor],"actor2")


  "MyWebSocketActor receive function" should {

    "have username key" in {

      val testActor = system.actorOf(Props(new MyWebSocketActor(actor1 , actor2, mockCache , mockMap)))

      val testMsg1 = Json.parse("""{"message":"Testing Message 2","conn_status":2,"pub_key":"empty","target":"all"}""")

      testActor ! testMsg1




    }


  }


}
```

I am working in Play 2.5.3 and Scala using Akka 2.4.7 . I have a class that looks like this class `MyWebSocketActor(out:ActorRef,postActor:ActorRef,cache:CacheApi,postActorToUsernameMap:Map[ActorRef,String]) extends Actor`

I wanted to create an actor of this class and call its receive function. I have tried as suggested in this link **[Akka Java : create an actor with constructor taking parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076721/akka-java-create-an-actor-with-constructor-taking-parameters)** also. But every time it gives me errors:-

**too many arguments for constructor MyWebSocketActor: ()test.MyWebSocketActor**

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: did it solve your problem?

Comment: Yes Sir my mistake. But there are other errors also. I won't mention coz that is not related to this thread. Thanx

Comment: awesome, happy to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actor `MyWebSocketActor` is being shadowed by your test suit. Change your test class to something else than `MyWebSocketActor`, for example `MyWebSocketActorTest`